# C# Console logging Program+SqlObject instead of key:value pairs

Tags: c#, .net

im trying to loop through my list but im getting Program+SqlObject instead of the objects values im new to c# so this is very confusing.

I think i should be getting something like 0:{id:value,date:value,Quantity:value} ,1:{id:value,date:value,Quantity:value} but instead im getting Program+SqlObject Program+SqlObject

here is the console output:

```
0: Add New Date

1: View Current Dates

2: Delete Date

3: Update Date



Program+SqlObject
Program+SqlObject
Program+SqlObject
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
    using System.Collections.Generic;







internal class Program
{


    struct SqlObject
    {


        public int id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        




            string inputCommand;
            string globalDateInput;
            int globalQuantityInput;
            while (true)
            {



                Console.WriteLine("\n\n0: Add New Date");
                Console.WriteLine("\n1: View Current Dates");
                Console.WriteLine("\n2: Delete Date");
                Console.WriteLine("\n3: Update Date");



                inputCommand = Console.ReadLine();


                CreateDatabase();
                CheckInput();

            }


            static void CreateDatabase()
            {
                using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Databases\HabitTrackerV3.db"))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    var command = connection.CreateCommand();

                    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS drinking_water (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,date Date, Quantity INTEGER)";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    connection.Close();


                }
            }



            void ViewDates()
            {

                using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Databases\HabitTrackerV3.db"))
                {
                   
                connection.Open();


                Console.WriteLine("Ran");
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM drinking_water ";

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("looped");
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        int id = (reader.GetInt32(0));
                        string Date = (reader.GetString(1));
                        int Quantity = (reader.GetInt32(2));

                        List<SqlObject> sqlList = new List<SqlObject>();
                        sqlList.Add(new SqlObject {id = id,date = Date,quantity=Quantity });
                        sqlList.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

                    }
                }

                   


                    connection.Close();


                }
            }


        void AddDate()
        {
            DateInputCommand();
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Databases\HabitTrackerV3.db"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var command = connection.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO drinking_water(date,Quantity) VALUES('{globalDateInput}' ,{globalQuantityInput})";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                connection.Close();


            }


        }


        void DateInputCommand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n What Date in the format dd-mm-yyyy");
            globalDateInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How many cups of water did you drink?");
            globalQuantityInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());




        }

        void CheckInput()
        {
            switch (inputCommand)
            {
                case "0":
                    AddDate();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    ViewDates();
                    break;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not format you code properly?  60 blank lines in 170 lines of code is unreadable.

Comment: You have one line in the wrong place.  Move before the while loop : List<SqlObject> sqlList = new List<SqlObject>();  and this line is wrong : sqlList.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));  You have to write each item one at time of : sqlList.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("id = {0}, date = {1}, quantity = {2}", i.id,i.date, i.quantity));

Answer (score 2):

The way you call it `Console.WriteLine` call implicitly `ToString` method of `object` type, so you need to be more explicit there.

So as mentioned one option is to override `ToString` method.

Other solution might be just to define more elaborate message in `Console.WriteLine`:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Fetched {i.Id} with date {i.date}")
```

or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the ToString() method in your type.

```
class SqlObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {id} date: {date}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, OP is getting a lot of nice comments what to improve, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

only change this line :

```
sqlList.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

to:

```
 sqlList.ForEach(i => 
Console.WriteLine("id: " + i.id+ ",date: "+i.date+", Quantity: "+i.quantity));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `record` instead of `struct`, which has it's own `ToString()` implementation that serializes all the properties.

To do that replace

```
struct SqlObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

with

```
record SqlObject(int Id, string Date, int Quantity);
```